# Non constant real valued expression not supported

Tags: vhdl

We are implementing Least Mean Squares (LMS) algorithm. If we add line 5 and line 6 (as indicated by comments below), we are getting an error right from line 1 (as indicated by comments) that

> non constant real valued expression not supported

However when we omit line 5 and line 6, we are not getting the error. Please help. Please ignore the STD_LOGIC_VECTORS(in and out)added in the beginning, as they are reserved for future use.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_signed.all;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity lms2 is
    Port (wr9,wi9,xr,xi : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 downto 0);
           --u : in integer;

           yr,yi,er,ei,wr8,wi8,zzz,sum1 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 downto 0));
end lms2;

architecture Behavioral of lms2 is
signal a,b :real;
--signal yr11, yi11 : real;

--variable r,s : real range 0.0 to 15.0;

begin

process(wr9,wi9,xr,xi)--process also runs without the parameters,but it gives problems during simulation
--process(u,xr,xi)
variable wr : std_logic_vector(12 downto 0);
variable wi : std_logic_vector(12 downto 0);

--variable wr : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) :="00010";
--variable wi : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) :="00011";
--variable wr : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) :=wr9;
--variable wi : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) :=wi9;
variable xr1 : real :=3.2;
variable xi1 : real :=4.1;
variable dr1 : real :=5.2;
variable di1 : real :=4.4;
variable yr1 : real;
variable yi1 : real;
variable er1 : real;
variable ei1 : real;
variable wr1 : real := 1.8;
variable wi1 : real := 2.1;
variable u   : real :=0.2;

variable f : real := 3.2;
variable g : real := 2.6;
variable h : real;
variable hh : real;

begin

h := f+g;
hh := f*g;
a <= h;
b <=hh;

--process(xr,xi,u)
--bi <= to_integer(unsigned(k)) ;
--bj <= to_integer(unsigned(l)) ;
--bk <= bi*bj;

for z in 0 to 3 loop

    yr1 := wr1*xr1-wi1*xi1;--line1
    yi1 := wr1*xi1+wi1*xr1;--line2

    er1 := (wr1*xr1)-(wi1*xi1)-dr1;--line3
    ei1 := (wr1*xi1)+(wi1*xr1)-di1;--line4

    wr1 := u*(xr1*er1-xi1*ei1)+wr1;--line5
    wi1 := u*(xr1*ei1+xi1*er1)+wi1;--line6

end loop;

--yr11 <= yr1;
--yi11 <= yi1;

end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Use the synthesisable fixed or floating point libraries, if your synth tool supports VHDL-2008. For older VHDL versions, see ... oops, does anybody know where http://www.eda.org/fphdl went?

Comment: [IMPORTANT: You cannot define a synthesizable object of type real](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2015_3/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf#143).  Your error message would be easier to find if you had left the hypens in.

Comment: [Synth 8-502] non-constant real-value expression is not supported

Answer (score 2):

The Xilinx synthesis tool does not support inferred floating point arithmetic from the `real` type. You need to open CoreGen or IP catalogue from within Xilinx ISE or Vivado, and use this to generate the floating point functions that you need.

Comment: Isnt Fixed point arithmetic not posible in vhdl...cant we represent floating point numbers using that...

Answer (score 0):

Though the code is not synthesizable(showing synthesis error), it can be used for simulation.Not synthesisable means cannot be burnt into an fpga kit. Simulation of this code will give no error